# Why are charge pumps only used for low current applications?

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, switch-mode-power-supply, inductor, charge-pump

Typically the most expensive (and hard to get) elements in a SMPS are the inductors. Thus I was wondering if it's possible to use inductor-less switching mode power supplies (i.e. charge pumps) for generic use cases, for example a bench-top power supply, fixed high power DC-DC converters (several amperes and some hundred watts power), etc.

All charge pump designs I could find though were for low power applications. What prevents one from designing a high power inductor-less power supply? Are there some inherent physical limitations?

Comment: I suspect that inductors can store more energy per unit volume/cost than capacitors - try the back-of-an-envelope calculation for what size of capacitors you would need for a hypothetical charge pump.

Comment: There are charge-pump / capacitive switcher ICs but these are usually only for very low power. I also expect that you would need very large capacitors. I also expect inductors to be less lossy.

Comment: @pjc50 With a 50kHz switching frequency, I could easily come up with a 20A, 24V to 12V step-down converter, with capacitors in the range of 10uf. The simulation also looks promising. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you included some realistic ESR (series resistance) for those capacitors ? Simulators are like paper: you can make anything work/not work on them ;-)

Comment: @FakeMoustache Yes. And agreed!

Comment: A properly built switching power supply needs a PCB and it is the PCB thsat is likely to be the most expensive and hard to get item because you have to design it!

Comment: @Andyaka The PCB is neither the most expensive nor the hardest to get item.

Comment: A 10uF capacitor supplying 10A will drop one volt per microsecond.  At a 50Khz switching frequency, you'd be looking at 100% ripple.

Comment: If one wanted to e.g. convert 24V to 9V, one could tolerate a two-volt drop over the course of 20us, so a 100uF cap would work (two volts of ripple, plus other losses, could total under three volts).  Efficiency would be about 75%, pretty much independent of ESR or other such issues, but something in the circuit would have to dump 60 watts of heat somewhere.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are two problems with your idea. One practical, and one fundamental.

The practical problem is that per amount of stored energy capacitors are more expensive than inductors, and on top of that the realy high-capacity capacitors (electrolytic) age.

The fundamental problem is that charging a capacitor from a voltage source is fundamentally lossy (you dissipate heat). This might seem counter-intuitive, but is nonetheless true. (There was a question about this some time ago.) Hence a flying-capacitor voltage converter, even an ideal one, is inherently inefficient. (An ideal inductor-based voltage converter is 100% efficient.)

You might think it strange that the world is unfair to capacitors, but that is our human fault: we supply power mostly from voltage sources. For current sources the inverse is true: an ideal current converter from flying capacitors can be 100% efficient, while one from inductors must necessarily be lossy.

Comment: Thanks. I cannot get my head around the fact that capacitors are more expensive than inductors (in a SMPS setting). My experience is that, at least for low quantities, I need to do some calculations, buy specific cores and wires and wind the wire around the core myself. It's very time consuming. While with a capacitor, I just buy a ready made one.
On the other hand, I'm an absolute newbie in SMPS domain, so probably there are better ways around.

Comment: You surely can buy ready-made inductors! But pay attention to my second point: a capacitor-based voltage converter is inherently lossy. No way around that.

Comment: Looks like I said essentially the same thing.. later. oops.

Comment: @Lazarus there are plenty of inductors available off the shelf. Ti have a tool called webbench that will do the design for you including calculating the efficiency and telling you exactly what parts to buy. The only issue i've found with it is it has a tendency to default to parts that are a PITA to solder.

Comment: Huh, nice (+1's everywhere.)  Is this the previous question? http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/54992/can-a-charge-pump-be-100-efficient-given-ideal-components.  I knew about caps and voltage sources... but never really thought about it!

Comment: Yep, thanks George, that is the one I had in mind.

Comment: Doesn't the fundamental inefficiency tend towards 0 as the frequency goes to infinity? (Or as the output current goes to 0)

Comment: Where have I seen the last paragraph before?

Comment: @immibis, an idealised charge pump tends towards perfect efficiency as the freqency tends to infinity or the load tends to zero. Any real converter will of course tend towards zero efficiency as the load tends to zero load because of quiescent current.

Comment: No, an idealised voltage charge pump will NOT converge to perfect efficiency for any non-zero output current. You can't beat nature: charging the capacitor will ALWAYS incurr a fixed lost (and discharging too). Even with all components converging to perfection.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen Isn't the loss per cycle proportional to CdV^2, where dV is the amount of voltage change in one cycle, which is proportional to 1/f? So at a higher frequency you have more cycles, but still less loss: C(1/f)^2 * f = C/f.

Comment: If memory serves, charging a capacitor through just a resistor (which will be just the resistance of a wire) is only 50% efficient.

Comment: @Lazarus Your experience only proves how easily available inductors are - so easy that you can custom-tailor them by hand and avoid compromising efficiency of the design.

Comment: @Agent_L can you point me to any reference for more details please ?

Comment: @Lazarus You are my source. You said that you design and produce your own inductors (as many people do). Can't do that with a capacitor, can you? Ergo, parts simpler to produce are cheaper when compared under same circumstances. (comparing custom-made inductors with off-the-shelf caps wasn't fair).

Comment: @Agent_L Oh, I meant a reference for more details on how to custom tailor inductors by hand, not a reference to support your claim :)

Comment: This answer compares charge pumps and inductor based DC-DC converters in the view of cost and efficiency. It doesn't answer why charge pumps are used for low current applications.

Comment: It does: when compared for stored energy, capacitor are much more expensive than inductors, and a capacitor-based converter is less efficient. (only) At sufficient small power levels, either argument is important, and the fact that *small* capacitors are chaper than *small* inductors can be more important.

Comment: I don't fully agree that there is some inherent problem in capacitor charge pumps regarding losses. If that was true, this device would not be possible: http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/7820fb.pdf

Comment: @payala - I agree. The LTC7820 chip you referenced converts 500 watts plus, at more than 90% efficiency, doubling the voltage or cutting it in half. People won't do what they think they cannot do. Perhaps that is the reason...

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD I have been getting efficiencies around 95% while transferring more than 2000W with a power stage based on the LTC7820 modified with external FETs. It's the closest thing to an ideal 4 quadrant middle rail generator. Compact, and so efficient you don't need heatsinks.

Answer (score 4):

Capacitors would be better if the source and output were constant current. You could charge the capacitor until the voltage rose to a certain level, then discharge the capacitor into the load impedance to maintain a constant output current. You'd use a big inductor as an output filter to maintain the output current constant.

Since our sources are constant voltage and we usually want constant output voltage, using inductors to store energy and capacitors to filter it makes more sense.

Note that all efficient switching supplies have **both** capacitors and inductors.

Yes, charge pumps (flying capacitor) can take a voltage and move it around, flip it, even multiply by integers and such like, but every time you charge or discharge a capacitor through a resistive switch you lose a portion of the capacitor's energy change in the switch itself - a larger voltage change means more losses. A lower resistance switch just means that the energy lost for a given voltage change is compressed into a smaller slice of time, the total remains constant.

Comment: "every time you charge or discharge a capacitor through a resistive switch you lose half the capacitor's energy change in the switch itself." that is true if you fully charge and discharge the capacitor each time. If you only discharge it partially you can do better.

Comment: @PeterGreen "change in energy" not total energy.

Comment: Lets say a 1 farad capacitor starts at 5V and is charged to 6V through a resistor from a 6V source. Energy in capacitor before =  0.5 * 1 * 5 * 5 = 12.5 . Energy in capacitor after = 0.5 *1 *6*6 = 18 . Energy added to capacitor = 18-12.5 = 5.5. Energy drawn from supply = (6-5) *1 *6 = 6 . Only 0.5 joules of energy are lost to add 5.5 joules of energy to the capacitor.

Comment: When charging a capacitor from zero to full through a resistor you do indeed lose half the energy but the ratio of energy added verses energy lost is not constant. The early stage of the charge is very lossy, the late stage very efficient.

Comment: "You could charge the capacitor until the voltage rose to a certain level, then discharge the capacitor into the load impedance to maintain a constant output current." - [as it turns out, this is just a buck converter with an extra capacitor on the input](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/215985/what-is-this-circuit-called-dual-of-a-boost-converter/).

Comment: @immibis [SEPIC](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c8/SEPIC_Schematic.gif/500px-SEPIC_Schematic.gif) topology is along similar lines.

Comment: @PeterGreen I suppose if the flying capacitor is only slightly discharged the charge pump may be more efficient, but I guess that also means you're drawing a relatively small current from the flying capacitor, or have a very huge capacitor at which point an inductor is smaller and more cost effective. That may be why charge pumps are only used for low-current applications.

Answer (score 3):

If two capacitors or series strings of capacitors with different voltages are connected together, their charges will average out in a way which reduces the amount of energy stored therein.  If they are connected using an inductor, the excess energy will be transferred to that inductor and may subsequently be put to some useful purpose.  If the connection is purely resistive, the energy will be 100% converted to heat.  Minimizing the resistance will not reduce the energy loss; it will merely reduce the amount of time required for it to occur.

Consequently, in order for a charge pump to be efficient, the capacitors need to be large enough that voltage across them never varies very much.
In cases where a charge pump doesn't need to convey much energy, one can
use a linear regulator on the output and boost the voltage enough that
under worst-case ripple conditions the output voltage will still be high
enough to maintain regulation, but efficiency will be limited by the
ratio of the load voltage times the boost ratio to the source voltage.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments of [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/216099/268467), switched capacitor DC-DC converters, such as one built around an [LTC7820](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/7820fc.pdf), can be extremely efficient (99% efficiency claimed in that datasheet) and can handle relatively high power (500 W claimed in the same datasheet).

The main disincentives to switched capacitor DC-DC converters have been

- the cost of storing energy in a large peak-energy capacitor, versus storing the same energy in a large peak-energy inductor,
- the physical bulk of large peak-energy capacitors
- the limited lifespan of electrolytic capacitors
- the inability of switched capacitors to efficiently convert DC to DC at ratios other than the ratio of small integers. One cannot smoothly adjust the output voltage of such a switched capacitor DC-DC converter, without a loss in efficiency.

The cost/benefit analysis for capacitors as energy storage devices, however, has shifted somewhat due to the development of super-capacitors.

The bulk of super-capacitors is smaller than previous generation capacitors and their lifespan is longer than electrolytics. Unfortunately they are still quite expensive.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with charge pumps.

1. they can't offer efficiency and voltage regulation at the same time. The only way to regulate the output voltage so that it remains constant during input voltage variations and load variations is to introduce deliberate inefficiency.
2. Current must pass through two switching elements (diodes or transistors) during both the charging and discharaging parts of the cycle (whereas with a buck or boost converter it only needs to pass through one switching element at a time).
3. Efficiency is highly dependent on the desired input to output voltage ratio. If you want to make say a 1.5x voltage converter then you would have to either use some complex multi-stage arrangement or make a 2x converter and run it in a deliberately inefficient mode.

Comment: Re point 3, any integer ratio is possible efficiently without much added complexity.  For 1.5x, charge the caps in 2-series connections (so each sees 0.5x the supply voltage), and discharge in 3-series.

Answer (score 0):

> at least for low quantities, I need to do some calculations, buy specific cores and wires and wind the wire around the core myself. It's very time consuming.

Instead, see what suitable fixed inductors are available and design the converter around those. That is pretty much how it's done for low volumes unless some extreme circuit optimization is required by the end application.

Inductors for most popular SMPS applications are really jellybean parts, and are plentiful and are extremely cost-optimized. There's big competition in the fixed inductor market and there's quite a pressure to keep the prices down as far as they can go.

Answer (score -2):

Charge pumps are DC circuits, based on capacitors. As capacitors charge, current flow reduces. To increase current, and hence more charge into capacitor, one would have to increase voltage, but capacitors have a voltage limit.

Inductors on the other hand, have very low ohmic resistance so high currents can pass through them even at low voltages. Hence buck/boost converters for power applications are based on both, capacitors & inductors.

Charge pumps are good for information processing though, by manipulating voltages and very efficient since they work with low currents eg. arithmetic and clamper circuits. Not good for power applications though, not *bench-top power supply and not fixed high power DC-DC converters*.

Comment: Capacitors have zero impedance at DC. Can you explain in what way these are DC circuits? It's my understanding they work in fact by switching the capacitor, so quite many AC frequencies are involved.

Comment: AC circuits also have negative voltage, current flow reverses periodically. DC circuits only have positive voltage & current.

Comment: @TimWilliams, capacitor has infinite impedance at DC

Comment: Apologies, conductance is zero, heh. In any case, that doesn't seem very useful. How do you transfer power through an open circuit?

Comment: Here's an article showing a charge pump to [invert voltage](https://maker.pro/custom/tutorial/how-to-access-negative-voltage-power-supply). A capacitor makes an open circuit for DC, but fluctuating electric field in capacitor is what allows power transfer

Comment: But it's not really "DC" if there's fluctuations, is it? "DC" implies static, unchanging forever.

Comment: DC means it's flowing in one direction, direct. AC voltage inverts/alternates to different direction, so goes negative. DC only has positive voltage

Comment: That is not a well accepted definition of "DC" I'm afraid.

Comment: DC does not reverse, it remains DIRECTed in one DIRECTion, with varying amplitudes, even from batteries. You may prove this with oscilloscope; any DC source can be proven to vary. eg. MPPT circuits work by varying voltages to maximize power transfer efficiency from wind turbines or solar panels, which are DC devices. Contrary to your understanding, these are not AC devices.

Comment: A varying DC source can be made to supply AC by a serial capacitor, as in the case with radio (wave) tuner/receivers.

Comment: DC doesn't imply "static, unchanging forever". DC means flowing in one direction, without regard to amplitude. Amplitude is a necessary attribute of AC because to reverse direction, current amplitude has to approach zero, then surpass it, to change direction.