# Switched capacitor DC-DC converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, switching-regulator

Switched capacitor DC-DC converters are often used for low power applications (low output current) while inductor based DC-DC converters are preferred for high power applications.

I've come across many research papers which make this claim but none actually clarifies the underlying reason.

Can someone please explain why switched capacitor power converters are only preferred for low power applications?

Comment: They have a bad efficiency and can't provide much output current. I guess your specific question is, what is the reason/physics/math/theory why switched capacitor DC/DC converters have bad efficiency and why they can't provide much output current?

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Yes, I want some mathematics and proof which justify how efficiency suffers with high output current

Comment: Analog Devices seems to have a design handbook for power and thermal design, Section 4 is about switched cap converters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are charge pumps only used for low current applications?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/216094/why-are-charge-pumps-only-used-for-low-current-applications) (Unfortunately, the top answer rather misses the point; it may be worth editing.)

Comment: These are usually called charge pumps, which is a term that might get you more results in a search.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments of [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/216099/268467) to a similar question, switched capacitor DC-DC converters, such as one built around an [LTC7820](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/7820fc.pdf), can be extremely efficient (99% efficiency claimed in that datasheet) and can handle relatively high power (500 W claimed in the same datasheet).

The main disincentives to switched capacitor DC-DC converters have been

- the cost of storing energy in a large peak-energy capacitor, versus storing the same energy in a large peak-energy inductor,
- the physical bulk of large peak-energy capacitors
- the limited lifespan of electrolytic capacitors
- the inability of switched capacitors to efficiently convert DC to DC at ratios other than the ratio of small integers. One cannot smoothly adjust the output voltage of such a switched capacitor DC-DC converter, without a loss in efficiency.

The cost/benefit analysis for capacitors as energy storage devices, however, has shifted somewhat due to the development of super-capacitors.

The bulk of super-capacitors is smaller than previous generation capacitors and their lifespan is longer than electrolytics. Unfortunately they are still quite expensive.